# Django Celery, Celery beat workers

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

In celery I've 3 types of tasks first task executes in every 3 minutes and take almost 1 minute to complete, second task is periodic which runs on every monday and takes almost 10 minutes to complete, the third and last one is for sending users emails for register/forget password, I'm confused how many workers/ celery beat instances I should use, can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'll have only one Celery beat instance to schedule your tasks. If you have more than one instance, it will lead to tasks being scheduled as many times as the number one Celery beat instances you have.

There's no hard and fast rule for how many Celery workers you should have. Start with a handful, e.g. three, and keep an eye on the metrics (you can use something like https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html to create dashboards).